# Flutter - Error while buiiding the apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

> The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin.
>   The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.

I'm using Android Studio for flutter, while building apk, build failed with above exception.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':path_provider:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> >
> > Android resource linking failed
>
> ```
>  /Users/android/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7faf2ad74a0b9932e38d86e684646e95/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25:
> ```
>
> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> ```
>  /Users/android/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7faf2ad74a0b9932e38d86e684646e95/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25:
> ```
>
> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

What is causing this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of path_provider you are using ?

Comment: Open android folder and run the app, check the error and also check the version of build.gradle

Comment: @A R `path_provider: ^0.4.1`

Comment: if problem persists run `flutter clean` and then run your project

Comment: @ G griffo, I done what u said, `flutter clean` solved the issue, but still the content of app not visible. `body:` is not visible in app. Is this because of the builded apk file.

Answer (score 0):

> Flutter Clean and update your package path_provider